# How to keep the right alignment in the div table in html page?

Tags: html, css

[Link for the table](https://github.com/Hariumesh03/Muscian_Test_App/blob/master/issue.png)I am trying to create a table using div with below code .

I need to get the right table alignment with rows and column.

Below are the css

```css
.Table {
  display: table;
}

.Title {
  display: table-caption;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: larger;
}

.Heading {
  display: table-row;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.Row {
  display: table-row;
}

.Cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Heading">

  <div Class="Cell">
    <p>PROJECT</p>
  </div>
  <div Class="Cell">
    <p>APPLICATION</p>
  </div>
  <div id="test">
    <span id="headerID1" class="Cell">
            <p>PRIMARY</p>
        </span>
    <span id="headerID2" class="cell">
            <p>DISASTER</p>
        </span>
    <span id="Time" class="Cell">   
            <P> LAST CHECKED TIME</P>                
         </span>

  </div>

</div>


<div class="Heading">
  <div Class="Cell">
    <p>GRABCDH</p>
  </div>
  <div Class="Cell">
    <p>abc.com</p>
  </div>
  <div id="test">
    <span id="PABC.th" class="Cell">
                <p>ABCD</p>
            </span>
    <span id="DABC.th" class="cell">
                <p>BCDE</p>
            </span>
    <span id="EABC.th" class="Cell">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="Heading">
  <div Class="Cell">
    <p>LEABCDE</p>
  </div>
  <div Class="Cell">
    <p>bcd.com</p>
  </div>
  <div id="test">
    <span id="Pdet.in" class="Cell">
                <p>HDCF</p>
            </span>
    <span id="Dladt.in" class="cell">
                <p>TDCP</p>
            </span>
    <span id="lADV.in" class="Cell">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="Heading">
  <div Class="Cell">
    <p>LABCD</p>
  </div>
  <div Class="Cell">
    <p>CDE.COM/p>
  </div>
  <div id="test">
    <span id="PCDE" class="Cell">
                <p>SBCD</p>
            </span>
    <span id="DABC.in" class="cell">
                <p>HABCD</p>
            </span>
    <span id="EABC.in" class="Cell">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="Heading">
  <div Class="Cell">
    <p>LDXY</p>
  </div>
  <div Class="Cell">
    <p>BCD.IN</p>
  </div>
  <div id="test">
    <span id="PDER.int" class="Cell">
                <p>HDC2</p>
            </span>
    <span id="DlyD.int" class="cell">
                <p>PLAN3</p>
            </span>
    <span id="lynCD.int" class="Cell">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

But the alignment not looks correct. 
Please let me know how can make this alignment proper?
The cell and row alignment get changed based on the text inside as seen in the above link

Comment: What do you actually expect and in what way doesn't this code meet your expectations?

Comment: Hi @Dragonthoughts i have shared the link of the table , that's what actually shows.

Comment: and what i am looking for now is, following values in the column should align properly
PRIMARY, DISASTER, LAST CHECKED TIME

Comment: Please clarify IN the question expected results (I am not going to click any link) the meaning of "keep the right alignment" when you have clearly center and not right with `.Cell` and `text-align: center;` so the "correct" alignment is what? (yes I know this looks like I am picking a bit but guessing is not efficient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a commun wrapper from which you can set the `table-layout` , then each sublevel is to receive the proper `display` for what it is supposed to do.

example of how you could start .

```css
.tableLayout {
  display:table;
}
.tableLayout > div{
  display:table-row;
}
.tableLayout > div > div {
  display:table-cell;
  border:solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableLayout">
  <div class="Heading">
    <div Class="Cell">
      <p>PROJECT</p>
    </div>
    <div Class="Cell">
      <p>APPLICATION</p>
    </div>
    <div id="test">
      <span id="headerID1" class="Cell">
            <p>PRIMARY</p>
        </span>
      <span id="headerID2" class="cell">
            <p>DISASTER</p>
        </span>
      <span id="Time" class="Cell">   
            <P> LAST CHECKED TIME</P>                
         </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Heading">
    <div Class="Cell">
      <p>GRABCDH</p>
    </div>
    <div Class="Cell">
      <p>abc.com</p>
    </div>
    <div id="test">
      <span id="PABC.th" class="Cell">
                <p>ABCD</p>
            </span>
      <span id="DABC.th" class="cell">
                <p>BCDE</p>
            </span>
      <span id="EABC.th" class="Cell">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Heading">
    <div Class="Cell">
      <p>LEABCDE</p>
    </div>
    <div Class="Cell">
      <p>bcd.com</p>
    </div>
    <div id="test">
      <span id="Pdet.in" class="Cell">
                <p>HDCF</p>
            </span>
      <span id="Dladt.in" class="cell">
                <p>TDCP</p>
            </span>
      <span id="lADV.in" class="Cell">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Heading">
    <div Class="Cell">
      <p>LABCD</p>
    </div>
    <div Class="Cell">
      <p>CDE.COM/p>
    </div>
    <div id="test">
      <span id="PCDE" class="Cell">
                <p>SBCD</p>
            </span>
      <span id="DABC.in" class="cell">
                <p>HABCD</p>
            </span>
      <span id="EABC.in" class="Cell">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Heading">
    <div Class="Cell">
      <p>LDXY</p>
    </div>
    <div Class="Cell">
      <p>BCD.IN</p>
    </div>
    <div id="test">
      <span id="PDER.int" class="Cell">
                <p>HDC2</p>
            </span>
      <span id="DlyD.int" class="cell">
                <p>PLAN3</p>
            </span>
      <span id="lynCD.int" class="Cell">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: `rowspan` or `colspan` attributes  have no equivalent in CSS, if you want some cells to be spanning through column or row, `display:grid` will be able to do it, please clarify if it is the case.

Comment: Hi @G-Cyr, this looks good. One question, if i need to bind some javascript, where i can bind it

Comment: @hanju what do you mean, what kind of script do you need ? it is regular html, so there is no peticular way to do it otherwise.

Comment: Seems this or perhaps some CSS like Bootstrap are the best guesses here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss bootstrap uses flex (or float for older version) , it draws row by row and do not care about columns if fixed width are not set .real  table behavior can only be achieve via the table-layout algorythm or via a mimic with display:grid which is quiet close

Comment: @G-Cyr - agreed, thus you did a good job of guessing the OP intent here!

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss i actually understood *right alignement* as *correct alignement* , i just realize it could be mistaken with horizontal direction . ;)